# Cant bind guake on F12 key

Tags: 13.10, guake

After ubuntu update to 13.10 guake didn't appear on F12 key.
I tried to change it to another F-key, but get message: "Unable to bind global F12 key".
Any ideas how to get this to work again?

Comment: I have the same problem on 14.04

Comment: I realized that I can't assign any command to toggle guake

Comment: Could tilde configuration be the problem? By default tilda likes to pop up on F12 and it keeps the keycode that starts it in its own configuration file.

Comment: The top answer on this question tackles and solves the problem.
https://askubuntu.com/q/1331707/1544200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was reported like a issue to guake, not seems to be a solution yet:

https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/316

Answer (score 10):

5 years later...

In GNOME 3.32, set a manual keybinding of "guake" to F12 in GNOME Settings > Keyboard, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but turning on the "**F Lock**" *(Function lock?)* key made the keybindings for me on an Ubuntu Mate 19.10 desktop with an old Microsoft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [totally different problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195364/ubuntu-screen-sharing-on-google-chrome-not-working) that solved this too:

Search for the `file.conf` in `/etc/gdm3/` in my case, Ubuntu 20, it's `custom.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment the line

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to be

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

then reboot.