# Ubuntu screen sharing on Google Chrome not working

Tags: 19.04

I'm trying to share my screen using Google Chrome or Microsoft Teams and I only can share the browser, I can't share my entire screen, it appears black:

Trying to select share full screen but it's black :

[image]

I thought the issues was due to having 3 monitors, but I disconnected both and still have the same issue. I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu and Google chrome, I also tried with chromium, and nothing.

I use this laptop for my work and I don't want to switch back to Windows... Programming on Windows is painfull, I need to get this to work.

**UPDATE**
I finally could fix it, seems like the issue is with wayland, switching to X.org fixes it.

This is the post that helped me: https://askubuntu.com/a/968265/1024151

Comment: Why the downvotes? something wrong? something I can improve, please let me know.

Comment: Pleaese consider writing your own answer by clicking the button below. Then and indicate that your answer is correct by clicking on the gray check mark  ✔ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others. Please **do not put the answer inside the question.**

Comment: Please post your update as an answer and removed it from your question. Q&A mechanism of SE won't work as expected if the question contains the answer.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Search for the **file.conf** in **/etc/gdm3/** in my case, Ubuntu 20, it's **custom.conf**

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

uncomment the line

`#WaylandEnable=false` to be `WaylandEnable=false`

then `reboot`

"*uncommenting that line will use the Xorg display manager instead of Wayland* "

Works on:
Ubuntu 20/21/22

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 21.10. Could you please explain, what does this configuration do? Thanks.

Comment: @kasi sorry for the late reply, uncommenting the above line will use the Xorg display manager instead of Wayland

Comment: this works for me in Ubuntu 21*

Comment: Works in 22.04.

Comment: Works perfect for me in Ubuntu 22. This solution is better than enabling : chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer, it causing my chrome crashed after share screen.

Comment: Turning off Wayland looks like an overkill. It turns off all the features supported by Wayland and not supported by X.org.

Comment: It is better to select X from the GDM login page. When you select the user, a cogwheel icon appears in the right-bottom corner.

Answer (score 48):

It was resolved by going to `chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer` and changing the value from `Default` to `Enabled`.

> After reboot Chrome, now the connection works well. Using the same test tools as before, now Chrome use the system selection window for share the screen or a window. Also Teams works well in Chrome over Wayland, and the black screen + mouse is now solved.

Source: https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux/issues/455

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for ubuntu 22.04. now i dont need to boot on my windows machine just to share screen on the meeting

Comment: That worked for me. I find this Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland too buggy. If anyone is planning to move to Ubuntu 22.04, I think it is much better to stay in 20.04. I'm planning to move back to 20.04. Every day this 22.04 presents a different error.

Comment: Thank you @kave-mcdaniel, this is the perfect solution!

Comment: I suggest marking this answer as the correct one. It fixes the problem within the Chrome browser, without affecting the whole operating system. The answer currently marked as correct is wrong in fact.

Comment: better solution than the chosen one

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 for sharing in Chrome

Comment: Also worked for me trying to get printscreen to work with maim, when printscreen chrome

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue, I resolved it by following below steps:

> Just go to the chrome browser search bar and enter:
> "chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer" -> Now set "WebRTC
> PipeWire support" flag to Enabled -> Relaunch chrome.

Now screen share will work.
[source](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux/issues/455)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's a Chrome bug, also happens for me in Ubuntu 20.04.

Workaround: While you are in the meeting, join the same meeting from another browser window/tab but this time as presenter. It will allow you to share things as expected: A whole screen, an application, Chrome tab, a specific window.

[see below both windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbZPB.png)
[image]
Left one as regular invited, right one as presenter, both in the same meeting.

Actually even after any fix, I will keep using it in this way since I can see what I'm sharing to others as others would see it, very convenient ;)

I know the answer is kind of late, but hope it helps to others with the same issue.

Comment: Ups, I didn't read well enough and the error it's for Microsoft Team, but something similar happens also for Google Meets, Slack and Jitsi meet, at least for me. So the answer I've sent might help others, but might not.

Answer (score 0):

Go to chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer using the address bar of your browser.
Change WebRTC PipeWire Support from Default to Enabled on the drop down menu.
Click Relaunch