# Unable to share application window to apps (Google Meet, Discord)

Tags: xorg, budgie

On 19.04 sharing application window in conferences worked perfectly.

Now using the version 20.04 when I try to share just one window it doesn't work anywhere: I tried Google Meet, Skype, Zoom, Hangouts, Discord and Microsoft Teams. That happens both on the browser (tried Chrome, Chrome Beta, Chromium and Firefox) and on the apps when available. Sharing the entire screen works.

[image: Google meet when I try to share applications]

Using Ubuntu version 20.04 LTS and my desktop is Ubuntu Budgie.

```
$ budgie-desktop --version
budgie-desktop 10.5.1

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

$ free -h
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1,5Gi        12Gi        92Mi       1,8Gi        13Gi
Swap:          15Gi          0B        15Gi

$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.12.0
```

[update]: updated my bios now.

Comment: @heynnema just put the infos you asked. My computer is a notebook, dell inspiron 7460. I have 1 TB SSD + 1 TB HD, 16 GB of RAM and a gpu of 4 GB, processor intel i5. I'm seriously thinking about reinstall the system and see if it works

Comment: Just boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if it works.

Comment: Hi @heynnema. I tried now to use the ubuntu live USB and it worked. Don't know why it doesn't on my system, but I'll try to reinstall in the root partition and see if it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Before you reinstall, create another user, called say, Guest. Log in there and see if the problem occurs there also. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema good idea. Tried that and the problem did not occurred. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that means the problem is specific to your account. Let me update my answer with a procedure to find where the problem is. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Please see the Update #1 in my answer. If it helps identify the problem, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema I did the proccess you suggested on all 3 folders but the problem still existis. I created another user and I'm using it, but I'll keep the old to see if that can be fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Then the process gets a little more difficult. Create a temporary folder on your Desktop. Move misc files/folders/.files out of /home/$USER to this temp folder... EXCEPT don't move files with **profile** or **bash** in the name (which is actually where the problem might be, especially if you've modified them), and don't move major folders like Documents/Pictures/etc. Log out. Log in. Retest.

Comment: @heynnema I'll try that during this week and keep you updated. Do you think it may have something to do with de nvidia drivers?  And also I've noticed something weird now: when I open chromium and try to share some application into one meeting, it shows some apps (like chromium windows, file explorer, text editor), but not google chrome, vscode, and some others.

Comment: No, if it had something to do with Nvidia, it would have also shown up in the Guest/other account. When you get to moving files/.files/folders/.folders, only do a few at a time, then log out, log in, retest. Start with .gconf, .gnome, and .gnome2. Otherwise, move about 25% at a time.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Dell Inspiron 7460

You have BIOS 1.11.0.

There's a newer BIOS available, 1.12.0, dated Mar 12, 2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=pmvdx&oscode=biosa&productcode=inspiron-14-7460-laptop).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Discord**

Know that Discord is basically spyware, in my opinion. It has code that determines what other software that you're running at the same time. That's none of "their" business. The snap version of Discord also bombs /var/log/syslog with error messages, unless you've given it permissions to go outside of its sandbox (bad idea).

**Update #1:**

We've isolated the problem to something in your own account.

I'll outline a procedure to try and isolate common trouble areas.

There are three folders that can typically cause problems:

- ~/.cache
- ~/.local
- ~/.config

The process is the same to eliminate **ONE FOLDER AT A TIME**. I'll use `~/.cache` as the example.

**Note**: It's normal for some system/application settings to change during this procedure. Screen resolution, etc. That's normal. Don't panic.

- rename `~/.cache` to `~/.cache.HOLD`
- a fresh new `~/.cache` folder will get recreated at log in
- log out of your account
- log back into your account
- try to recreate the sharing problem
- **if the problem still exists**, then `~/.cache` is not the problem, then do:
- MOVE the fresh new `~/.cache` folder out to the Desktop, we'll trash it later
- rename `~/.cache.HOLD` to `~/.cache`
- IMMEDIATELY log out
- log back in
- **if the problem is fixed**, then the problem exists in the `~/.cache.HOLD` folder, then do:
- MOVE, NOT COPY, everything from `~/.cache.HOLD` folder back into the fresh new `~/.cache` folder, SKIPPING any existing files
- anything left over in the `~/.cache.HOLD` folder is potentially bad
- done

Comment: hi @heynnema. I did the update of the BIOS, but the problem is still here.

Comment: about discord, it was just a test, but thank you for letting me know that, I had no idea

Answer (score 0):

Set **WaylandEnable=false** in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file

> sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

uncomment the line

> #WaylandEnable=false to WaylandEnable=false

this solution I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195364/ubuntu-screen-sharing-on-google-chrome-not-working/1309637#1309637)