# Screen share show black screen after upgrade from Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.10, 21.04

Screen share shows just a black screen after the upgrade from Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04. It was working fine until 20.10.

Tried in Google Chrome, Firefox, etc. all of them shows just the black screen. It is not related to the browser.

Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu screen sharing on Google Chrome not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195364/ubuntu-screen-sharing-on-google-chrome-not-working)

Answer (score 51):

An alternative solution, from:

- [How to disable Wayland and enable Xorg display server on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux/)
- [How to enable/disable wayland on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-20-04-desktop/)

```
sudoedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment the line

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

and save the change. This will enable the Xorg display manager.

Then either

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

Or just reboot the system.

---

This reportedly works on the following versions:

- 18.04
- 20.04
- 21.10
- 22.04 LTS
- 22.10

---

**Note**: When switching back to X11, make sure that you have the package `xserver-xorg-input-all` installed - otherwise your mouse and keyboard will *not* work.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. My system is running Ubuntu 21.10 with an nvidia graphics card.

Comment: This works for on 22.04 LTS too

Comment: This works for me also, ubuntu 22.04LTS

Comment: This works for me also, ubuntu 22.10

Answer (score 18):

Looks like Ubuntu 21.04 defaults to Wayland - when I switch to Xorg, screenshare works fine.

If anyone wants to try this, these are the steps:

1. In the login screen, click the setting icon
2. Choose "Ubuntu On Xorg" instead of "Ubuntu"
3. Now login

Screenshare should work now.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Chrome and prefer to use Wayland and do not want to switch back to Xorg, activate the following flag in the browser:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer
```

From the flag description:

> When enabled the WebRTC will use the [PipeWire](https://pipewire.org/) multimedia server for
> capturing the desktop content on the Wayland display server

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I tried @greenonline's solution and it worked, but my touchpad is not working. so I use your suggestion and solved blank screen issue and also my touchpad is working. I'm using ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Does something like this exist for Firefox too?

Comment: @GRASBOCK -  That seems like a good question to post