# Ubuntu 22.04. keyboard shortcut not working in terminal

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04, gnome-terminal

Hello Ubuntu Community,

i recently upgraded my Ubuntu to 22.04 and now I have a very weird problem. I am using copyq as a clipboard manager and my shortcut to activate it is [CTRL]+[<]. I am using a german keyboard so the [<]-key is a dedicated key at the bottom left. Before the upgrade, I could open the clipboard manager UI from every application. Since the upgrade, it still works at most of the applications but for the preinstalled terminal app it only inputs "<" into the terminal instead of opening the copyq application.

I have the feeling that the terminal is suppressing my input.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't you notice that the hotkey does not anymore work in more places, or is it just the terminal?

Comment: No, only in terminal. In all other places it works fine

Comment: Okay i found a "solution". I switched to xorg instead of wayland as described here (https://askubuntu.com/a/1341213) and now it works :)