# Failed to boot, black screen with cursor not responding

Tags: boot

My laptop is not booting, I get [these errors](https://imgur.com/a/J1Lcw1V) during a fraction of a second and then just black screen with pointer that does not respond.

This happened after following steps for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341208/screen-share-show-black-screen-after-upgrade-from-ubuntu-20-10-to-21-04)

I followed these steps:

```
1- sudoedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
2- uncomment #WaylandEnable=false
3- sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

And now my laptop will fail to boot, please help!

Comment: I think it might be in your interest to attempt to backtrack on that. Have you tried booting to a terminal level recovery mode and editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf from there, perhaps re-commenting WaylandEnable=false? You can usually do it either from GRUB or, I think, by holding Left Shift during a boot. That should give you a very basic terminal and not rely on anything Wayland or X11 would be doing.