# When I reboot Ubuntu but I can not open it again?

Tags: reboot

Update: I follow this to solve my screen sharing problem [Ubuntu screen sharing on Google Chrome not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195364/ubuntu-screen-sharing-on-google-chrome-not-working)
I have change some content in custom.conf file then I reboot I got this error and not able to start the computer again

[image: error image]

Comment: i can`t see any errors in the picture you have posted,please add more information to your question as it is now it contains to little information for anybody to solve it.

Comment: Really sorry for that now I can not open the computer. Just take a photo of erorr

Comment: You can click on the link you will see the photo

Comment: I have update may you check