# Google meet share window switch workspace

Tags: google-chrome

When I share a window in the Google Meet on workspace1, and I switch to workspace2 the shared window becomes a black screen. How can I change this behavior?

I got a related post [Ubuntu screen sharing on Google Chrome not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195364/ubuntu-screen-sharing-on-google-chrome-not-working)

Is it possible to switch some option in the Chrome to achieve that?

`chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer`

Comment: Can you try using x.org instead if wayland and check if the issue persists?

Comment: I use x.org and the issue persists

Comment: Any ideas on how to manage that?

Comment: In Firefox it works perfectly.