# F12 acting weird in 21.04, can no longer toggle Guake

Tags: function-keys, guake

Since upgrading to 21.04, I can no longer use Guake as expected.  My F12 key does not appear to function the way it used to.  It will not summon the Guake window, and when I manually open it, pressing F12 will not cause the window to hide.

Instead, pressing F12 prints a "~".  In fact, many function keys seem to, including F5 through F8, F10, and F12.  Interestingly, F11 does successfully toggle Guake in and out of fullscreen mode.

When I check the shortcuts in the Guake Preferences, F12 is mapped to "Toggle Guake visibility".  I can undo that mapping, set it to something else, and then successfully remap it to F12.  But no matter what I set it to, it won't respond.

I have tried apt purge on all things guake and reinstalled, but it hasn't fixed the problem.  Google hasn't been able to shed much light on this.  Can anyone suggest another solution?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *hirsute* hippo [21.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.04 is 22 April 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-schedule/18539) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: The released *beta* (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/04/01/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-final-beta-released/) or even installations or *daily* ISOs are currently the focus of *bug hunting, bug reporting & bug fixing* so all issues with hirsute (what will be 21.04 on release) should be on bug trackers so they issues are fixed prior to release. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand.  I'll file a bug report.  Thank you.

Comment: Filed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/guake/+bug/1924825

Comment: In Wayland, Guake is also unable to stay on top. The Guake developer doesn't seem to use Wayland, and doesn't seem interested in supporting it. I'm switching to ddterm: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3780/ddterm/. As a Gnome extension, it integrates better, and is inspired by Guake, so looks very similar.

Comment: Default boot into xorg instead of Wayland to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the result of an incompatibility with Wayland and guake.  To work around this issue, log into Ubuntu with Xorg instead.  It is a known issue to the guake development team: https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/1841

Comment: You can switch permanently to xorg (from Wayland) via the settings in the (Ubuntu) login screen. See here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/switch-xorg-wayland-ubuntu1710/. This is a fix for me, since guake is now working again. Also restart during this process or firefox etc may not open. Can default boot into xorg in future.

Comment: It is not an incompatibility. Wayland introduces security measures that Xorg lacks. Adding a hot-key seems to be [the official solution](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/1642#issuecomment-1001301695). Resorting to Xorg is literally moving backwards and, in due time, will be considered unsecure.

Answer (score 17):

If you wish to continue using the default Wayland, you can add the shortcut manually.

- Open Gnome settings
- Click Keyboard Shortcuts
- Scroll to the bottom and click '+'
- Enter name: Show / hide guake
- Enter command: guake-toggle
- Click Set Shortcut and set which shortcut key you'd like to use

Relevant guake issue: https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/1642

Specifically: https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/1642#issuecomment-580668579

Comment: thank you this is awsome!